# How to get executed client details inside PL/pgSQL function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

could you please let me know, how can i get the function executed client(single client only) details  inside the PL/pgSQL function(something `$whoexecuted`). i'm getting the current all active client details.
as per the following code.

```
begin
select ps.usename, ps.client_addr,ps.application_name from pg_stat_activity ps
where state = 'active'
and ps.usename in('user1') into pg_stat_activity_rowtype
;
```

Answer (score 0):

The content of pg_stat_activity is available from PLpgSQL too. So you can use

```
do $$
declare r record;
begin
  for r in select * from pg_stat_activity where pid = pg_backend_pid()
  loop
    raise notice '%', r;
  end loop;
end;
$$;
```

These data can be collected from some source:

```
select current_user, session_user, current_database(), inet_client_addr(), current_setting('application_name');
┌──────────────┬──────────────┬──────────────────┬──────────────────┬─────────────────┐
│ current_user │ session_user │ current_database │ inet_client_addr │ current_setting │
╞══════════════╪══════════════╪══════════════════╪══════════════════╪═════════════════╡
│ pavel        │ pavel        │ postgres         │                  │ psql            │
└──────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────────┴──────────────────┴─────────────────┘
(1 row)
```

More in documentation:

1. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html
2. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html